# How to use 'Exit For Loop IF' keyword with multiple condition in Selenium Robot framework

Tags: selenium, for-loop, if-statement, robotframework, built-in

I need to exit FOR LOOP in Selenium Robot framework when multiple conditions are met

I am trying something like this where it should exit FOR LOOP , if the below conditions are met:

```
Exit For Loop IF    '${Name}'=='Adam'   and '${Age}'=='27'
```

Error:

`Keyword 'BuiltIn.Exit For Loop If' expected 1 argument, got 2.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be careful that Robot Framework use [space separated format](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#space-separated-format).
I.e. Robot Framework will separate the `and` operator as a new argument since there is more than 2 spaces between the conditions.
That's why Robot Framework think you give two arguments instead of one and the execution will fail.

Please try make it one space.

```
Exit For Loop If    '${Name}'=='Adam' and '${Age}'=='27'
```